# Why does resolvconf change a domain to a search keyword?

Tags: resolvconf

I am trying to get a `domain xxx.yy` into the `/etc/resolv.conf`. Before, there are only nameserver entries. I add the domain to the previously empty `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`. After running `resolvconf -u`, `/etc/resolv.conf` contains a `search xxx.yy` instead of the `domain xxx.yy`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the `search` feature supersedes the `domain` feature. Unlike `domain`, `search` accepts multiple arguments.

Consider `domain` to be obsolete.